# ObjectiveC accessing base class properties in subclass?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I am new to ObjectiveC and I have following inheritance.

```
    @interface CGameEntity : NSObject {
        b2Body *entityBody;
    }

    @property(nonatomic,retain) CCSprite *entitySprite;

   -(id)initEntity:(CCNode*)parentNode :(b2World*)world;
   @end
```

implementation :

```
@implementation CGameEntity

@synthesize entitySprite=entitySprite;
.
.
.
@end
```

And extended class is as follows :

```
@interface CPlanet : CGameEntity {

}
@end
```

implementation is as follows:

```
@implementation CPlanet

-(id)initEntity:(CCNode*)parentNode :(b2World*)world
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        //cannot access "entitySprite" ????
        entitySprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"planet.png"];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In the extended class I cannot access the property "entitySprite".
How can I access properties of the base class ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, replace ...

```
@synthesize entitySprite=entitySprite;
```

By ...

```
@synthesize entitySprite;
```

Then, replace this line ...

```
entitySprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"planet.png"];
```

By this ...

```
self.entitySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"planet.png"];
```

This will work =)!

Comment: Any particular reason for entitySprite_ and not _entitySprite? I actually like the idea of postfixing the underscore for easier typing and autocompletion, but I was wondering whether you use that format all the time?

Comment: I prefer `_entitySprite` over `entitySprite_`, and more over, `_entitySprite` is synthesized by default. So you could replace `self.entitySprite` with `_entitySprite`, just make sure you're using ARC or know your way arround with ObjC's GC.

Comment: With the latest XCode you can leave it out altogether and it autosynthesises.